# yii2 rewrite model addError

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

this is original Model.php function

```
public function addError($attribute, $error = '')
{
    $this->_errors[$attribute][] = $error;
}
```

in my model property i want override this method in this way

```
public function addError($attribute, $error = '')
{
    if ($attribute == 'status'){
        $this->_errors[$attribute] = $error;
    }
    else{
        $this->_errors[$attribute][] = $error;
    }
}
```

I can't access at $this->_errors ...
I have no idea how i can override this funcion without modify main model.php

Comment: did you extended original Model.php class in your child class??

Answer (score 0):

found solution!
In personal model class add this

```
/**
 * @param array $errors
 */
public function setErrors($errors)
{
    $this->errors = $errors;
}
```

and in my validate function

```
$this->setErrors(['status' => false, $attribute => 'not found']);
```

without use addError function